xlsx-ls-style : Support for merged cell styles for iOS applications
I am having problems with the rendering of merged cells in iOS applications such as Numbers.
Here's a sample of my code. The resulting file will contain three cells that are merged.  If you open this file in Excel, the frame around the merged cells is drawn correctly. If we use the table preview in macOS or the "numbers" program, we will see that the borders are drawn incorrectly.
const XLSX = require('xlsx-js-style');

const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
const worksheet = {};

const borderStyle = {
        border: {top: { style: 'thin', color: { rgb: '000000' } },
        bottom: { style: 'thin', color: { rgb: '000000' } },
        left: { style: 'thin', color: { rgb: '000000' } },
        right: { style: 'thin', color: { rgb: '000000' } },
    }
};
const cellObj = { v: 'cell', s: borderStyle };

for (let row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    const cellAddress = A${row};
    worksheet[cellAddress] = { v: Row ${row}, s: borderStyle };
}

worksheet['!merges'] = [{ s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: 0, r: 2 } }];

worksheet['!ref'] = 'A1:A3';

worksheet['A1'] = cellObj;
worksheet['A2'] = cellObj;
worksheet['A3'] = cellObj;

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'testSheet');

XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'test.xlsx');

The task is to find a way to draw the frame in such a way that the Numbers application displays the frame correctly.
(The project that has this bug is very large and I cannot replace the library. Only if it has an identical API. For example SheetJs or its forks. I tried some popular forks, but the problem was also reproduced there.)
I know for sure that when saving, the cells that are merged exist until the file is created. I also tried several libraries with the same API (forks from sheetJs).
Also the exceljs library doesn't have the same problem. But I can't use this library.
If you correct the cell boundaries manually in the Numbers program and export the result to xlsx, the frame will be drawn correctly. I think this means that Numbers can be made to display the frames correctly using the xlsx-js-style library.

Consider adding an image to illustrate the issue.
